# Joining Two Same-Sized Resultsets by Row Number

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two table functions that return a single column each. One function is guaranteed to return the same number of rows as the other.

I want to insert the values into a new two-column table. One colum will receive the value from the first udf, the second column from the second udf. The order of the inserts will be the order in which the rows are returned by the udfs.

How can I JOIN these two udfs given that they do not share a common key? I've tried using a ROW_NUMBER() but can't quite figure it out:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.NewTwoColumnTable (Column1, Column2)
SELECT udf1.[value], udf2.[value]
FROM dbo.udf1() udf1
INNER JOIN dbo.udf2() udf2 ON ??? = ???
```

Comment: How do you guarantee the order of the rows coming out of the UDFs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will not help you, but SQL does not guarantee row order unless it is asked to explicitly, so the idea that they will be returned in the order you expect may be true for a given set, but as I understand the idea of set based results, is fundamentally not guaranteed to work properly. You probably want to have a key returned from the UDF if it is associated with something that guarantees the order.

Despite this, you can do the following:

```
declare @val int
set @val=1;

Select Val1,Val2 from 
(select Value as Val2, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by @val) r from udf1) a
join 
(select Value as Val2, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by @val) r from udf2) b
on a.r=b.r
```

The variable addresses the issue of needing a column to sort by.

If you have the privlidges to edit the UDF, I think the better practice is to already sort the data coming out of the UDF, and then you can add `ident int identity(1,1)` to your output table in the udf, which makes this clear.

The reaosn this might matter is if your server decided to split the udf results into two packets. If the two arrive out of the order you expected, SQL could return them in the order received, which ruins the assumption made that he UDF will return rows in order. This may not be an issue, but if the result is needed later for a real system, proper programming here prevents unexpected bugs later.

Comment: But how do you guarantee how the `identity` values are applied? Is there something in the data coming out of the UDF that you can already inherently use to dictate the order you want?

Comment: Canoehead: Thanks. It is clearer to explicitly return the value, especially if the UDF returns sorted values - integers are pretty narrow, so they add relatively little overhead. On the other hand, there are cases where, even if the code should, SQL really does not guarantee row order returned, as my last revision pointed out. Aaron - This is why a sequence can be used - ideally only if the row order is sorted coming out of the UDF.

Comment: All kinds of things can change the order that comes out of the UDF (or how identity values are applied) - statistics changes, data changes, index changes, service packs, hotfixes etc. If you are relying on the order without specifying an order, you're asking for trouble. In other words, adding an identity column to the UDF gives you a row number to associate with the other UDF, but it doesn't guarantee that it will be applied to the same row each time.

Comment: Aaron: Thanks. I am guessing you know more about this then I do. As I stated above, it is fundamentally not guaranteed to work correctly. Thansk for the details about what types of things could break it; I assumed that the UDF would have a specific order of output, and as of MS SQL2008, it can, certainly at least for CLR table valued UDFs, where the ORDER option is available.

Answer (score 3):

In `SQL`, the "order returned by the udfs" is not guaranteed to persist (even between calls).

Try this:

```
WITH    q1 AS
        (
        SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY whatever1) rn
        FROM    udf1()
        ),
        q2 AS
        (
        SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY whatever2) rn
        FROM    udf2()
        )
INSERT
INTO    dbo.NewTwoColumnTable (Column1, Column2)
SELECT  q1.value, q2.value
FROM    q1
JOIN    q2
ON      q2.rn = q1.rn
```

Comment: try to return row keys from udfs

Comment: @ShashwatShriparv: I'm not the op.

Comment: @Quassnoi: The whatever1 and whatever2 is exactly the problem. I don't have a key to order by.

Comment: @Canoehead: make your udfs to return it.

Comment: @Quassnoi: +1 for the reminder about non-guaranteed order of rows. But I've accepted David Manheim's answer because I think it is more complete in that he suggested the identity(1,1) in addition to the same advice about non-guaranteed order.

Comment: @Canoehead: I haven't advised it because I've seen the code relying on it break many times (the last week was one of them and it was a really nasty one). When I say "`UDF` order is not guaranteed", it's not "can possibly break in a future release" or "there is nothing is the manual which says it does", no. This means "it is not guaranteed, can change and will change, and I've seen it on real systems".

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL 9.4+ could append a INT8 column at the end of the udfs result using the `WITH ORDINALITY` suffix

```
-- set returning function WITH ORDINALITY
SELECT * FROM pg_ls_dir('.') WITH ORDINALITY AS t(ls,n);
       ls        | n
-----------------+----
pg_serial       |  1
pg_twophase     |  2
postmaster.opts |  3
pg_notify       |  4
```

official doc: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/functions-srf.html

related blogspot: http://michael.otacoo.com/postgresql-2/postgres-9-4-feature-highlight-with-ordinality/